# Module not appearing in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, python-import

I'm having issues with importing my modules into jupyter. I did the following:

1. Create virtual env
2. Activate it (everything below is in the context of my venv)
3. install yahoo finance module: `pip install yfinance`
4. open python console and import it to test if working > OK!
5. open jupyter notebook
6. `import yfinance` throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance`'

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue I used -

%pip install yfinance

It worked for me

Comment: Consider formatting the code part of your answer by using the relevant markdown options.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
pip3 install yfinance
```

---

If you are inside a conda environment, it might be better to use `conda install` that handles all the dependencies:

```
conda install yfinance
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one in your jupyter and the run it

!pip install yfinance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't recommend using an exclamation point with `pip` (or `conda`) in the future. Magic commands were added to help `pip` and `conda` work with the correct environments. For example, you should have recommended `%pip install yfinance`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information. Anything with an exclamation point in front of `pip` or `conda` is outdated advice. Automagics are usually on by default & so the % symbol gets added generally behind-the-scenes automatically when not included.