# import in jupyter notebook to use a method from another file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook. I have 3 jupyter source files written in python in a folder in the same directory: parser, preprocess, and temp. I am trying to import parser and import preprocess in the temp file so that I can use the methods written in those files.
Example: there is method named extract in parser file. I want to use that from temp file. How can I do that?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72019554/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712291/8508004) for some examples of importing functions from other python files. The first is specific to doing it in an Jupyter `.ipynb` notebook running with a Python kernel; however, this is broadly applicable to the Python ecosystem.

Comment: Okay, I just read one of your comments, that the other `preprocess` is in a Python-based notebook. That's slightly different. See [here](https://github.com/deathbeds/importnb#import-notebooks-from-files) about `importnb`. It makes what you want to do easier. It's sort of good I suggest importing from a Python script (`.py` source file first) because I'd suggest reading how to do it from a script first because it is the same concepts yet simpler, and then look at how it is being done from a notebook.

Comment: I just expanded an answer I had about `importnb` to add an example that might help you, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086016/8508004).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the files you need to import as py files. As an example, parser.ipynb can be converted to a python file parser.py, and you can import it from another notebook file. If you want to use a function named extract() from parser.py, just import

```
from parser import extract
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pip for installing packages. Open command propmpt (cmd) and type this below command

```
pip install preprocess
```

Comment: It is not a package. preprocess is also python code I have written in notebook.

Comment: Try to give different name to your code file and then try

Comment: I tried but still it shows the same error.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you answer now?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `pip install preprocess` from the terminal (or CMD, if you are using Windows). Alternatively, you can run `! pip install preprocess` from Jupyter Notebook itself, which will do the same thing. You may need the second one if you are working on Google Colab.

Comment: preprocess is another jupyter source file that I wrote in python.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you answer now?

Comment: @Jafar Isbarov. I know it isn't pertinent now because a published package isn't involved; however, I wanted to clue you in to avoiding suggesting using an exclamation point with `pip`. Basically, it can cause problems and is outdated advice. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72197390/8508004). Should be `%pip install <package name>`.

Comment: @Wayne Didn't know this, thanks!